# Dual Boot | Windows installed on plextor ssd | linux (failed) on samsung ssd

Tags: boot, windows

Right now I'm struggling to get my set-up working.
I intended a dual boot windows 10/ linux kde plasma 5 build which are both installed on different, empty drives.

My rig:

MoBo: MSI X370 gaming pro carbon
CPU: AMD Ryzen 1600x 3.2 GHZ
Ram: Corsair Vengeance 16GB DDR4-3200
GPU: Geforce GTX 760 4GB (to be replaced)
Drive1: plextor m.2 nvme ssd 500gb [windows installed]
Drive2&3: Samsung 850 evo 250GB raid1 [Linux failed to install]

If I'm missing out on any important information please let me know.

So far i followed these instructions to get my setup working:
"https://youtu.be/vxepmtjmilQ" 
-- > I kept getting the "failed to install grub-efi to /target/ error message and everything i found on the internet so far didn't fix it.
"https://youtu.be/Xw__bTvQKsY"
--> for some reason my ssd's don't show up in my bios as an available option...

Gladly appretiate any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the file that adds the efi-firmware option to the grub menu errors on some computers. grub installs but the initial grub-update to create the config file is what fails.

the file /etc/grubd/30_efi-firmware needs to be edited to remove the if/then statement. then update grub.

I've edited mine to read:

> gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2
>
> cat << EOF
> menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {
> fwsetup
> }
> EOF

if your installer has a command prompt at the bottom. you can make this change and reinstall grub (nano is the text editor. you may have to comment out the gettext_printf line also ).

if not then, continue with out installing grub, and make the change from a LiveCD. and update grub.